# Why setting focus on a hidden element has caused sidebar uncollapsable

Tags: visualforce

I have enabled collapse sidebar in my customize/user interface. On my Visualforce page, it works fine originally. But since my first element in the page is an inputField of a datetime type, and it auto pops up the datetime picker once re-load, I added the following code to set focus on a hidden elment.

In page:

```
<input id="hiddenElement" type="hidden" />
```

In JS:

```
window.onload = setFocus;

function setFocus() {
    document.getElementById("hiddenElement").focus();
}
```

This works fine but the issue with this is the sidebar suddenly refused to collapse.

I can walkaround this by putting this code into document.ready() - which might be a little bit unstable for setting focus. Or I can use the following code:

```
if (document.getElementById('sidebarDiv')){
        Sidebar.prototype.theSidebar = new Sidebar(document.getElementById('sidebarDiv'), true, false);
    }
```

But I am feeling confused about why setting focus on the hidden element during page loading has caused sidebar collapse stopped working. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is likely that you are overriding the window.onload handler, canceling code that Salesforce has assigned to to handle that event.  You can add a function to handle the onload in a way that won't interfere.  Here's an answer from the question "[adding to window.onload event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15564058/3210089)" that shows two functions being added:

> ```
> addEvent(window, 'load', function(){ some_methods_1() });
> addEvent(window, 'load', function(){ some_methods_2() });
>
> function addEvent(element, eventName, fn) {
>     if (element.addEventListener)
>         element.addEventListener(eventName, fn, false);
>     else if (element.attachEvent)
>         element.attachEvent('on' + eventName, fn);
> }
> ```